# Running out of partition space on existing Ubuntu 12.04.5 32-bit LTS installation

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, gparted

I have been running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit installation for 3 years and before the installation I had allocated separate partitions for `/home` and `/`, but as my hard drive space is limited I did not see much use of it since the files in `/home` directory is already in `/` directory as far as I understood, is my interpretation correct? Apart from that I am constantly getting low disk space warnings and would like to allocate bigger space for my `/home` and `/` partitions. How can I do that without messing up my system? I can shrink the partition name `DATA` in my system and move the mount point for root backwards, but I am afraid that this will lead to bigger problems. I am providing a SS from `Gparted` so that you can visualize the problem.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

to do it safely you remove space from DATA using windows (since partitioning using windows' Disk manager is safe). and leave that free space. and boot into live ubuntu using USB/DVD and merge that free space with `/` using gparted.

Comment: Okay I will merge that free space with the `/` mount point but how can I move its contents to the beginning?

Comment: @Vesnog i dont think you should move data, ext4 itself is a smart filesystem, new files might get stored in the beginning of the partition. dont worry about this

Comment: What about the adjacent home partition how can I increase its size too?

Comment: @Vesnog practically, we your system would never use swap(atleast on desktop). if it did use your system will get slower enough to make you system hang. so i dont use swap. you can include swap in home partition. and after trying tell whether partitioning was successful or not

Comment: @Vesnog i updated my above comment, you can safely merge swap with home

Comment: Thanks for your assistance I will let you know what happened after trying.